# Finding width of characters to do wordwrap

Tags: wpf, word-wrap

I'm writing a custom texteditor using WPF and am using a stack of `TextBlock`s to render the lines. That leads me to the problem to find when to **wordwrap** from one line to the next.

What is the best way to do this? Is there a way to find the width of each characther/glyph (other than creating a `FormatedText` class for each character)?

Answer (score 3):

I had to do this in order to solve [this problem](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/06/search-and-highlight-text-in-arbitrary.html). Maybe you could check out the code there. The relevant part of the code is:

```
var textPointer = run.ContentStart;
textPointer = textPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(start, LogicalDirection.Forward);
var leftRectangle = textPointer.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
textPointer = textPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(length, LogicalDirection.Forward);
var rightRectangle = textPointer.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Backward);
var rect = new Rect(leftRectangle.TopLeft, rightRectangle.BottomRight);
var translatedPoint = uiHost.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), null);
rect.Offset(translatedPoint.X, translatedPoint.Y);
```